# Assign operator to variable as function

Tags: swift

How can I assign, say, `<` operator to variable? I need this in extension:

```
extension: CollectionType where Generator.Element: Comparable {
    func someFunc {
        let op: (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool
        if <some_condition> {
            op = Self.Generator.Element.< // - this is not work
        } else {
            op = Self.Generator.Element.> // - this is not work
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In your case (assuming that your operator function signature is actually `(Self.Generator.Element, Self.Generator.Element) -> Bool`, otherwise it doesn't make much sense as `Self` isn't `Comparable`) you simply want `op = (<)`

Comment: Thank you! I should improve my google skills